# How to wait for completion of a Non-Restartable Job in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I've been converting a number of nightly scheduled jobs to run one after the next by making a job of jobs. This is totally legit in Spring Batch as a Step can be defined with a reference to another job.

The problem is some of the same child jobs are run on a schedule by Quartz, and they are non-restartable. This means sometimes the "job of jobs" fails because it tries to start an already running job. This yields the much loved:

```
JobRestartException: JobInstance already exists and is not restartable
```

My question is whether this is a way to tell Spring Batch to wail until the referenced job is available and then run it. This is because the nightly workflow requires A->B->C. I understand that I can write my own custom job launcher to poll the JobRepository for the offending child job's ExecutionStatus to complete, but I was hoping SB had already thought of this common problem.

**Update**, example of Job of Jobs for those who asked how it works. The **ref**'s point to jobs that are SimpleJob beans. This works well, but errors as described above when a child job is already running.

```
<!-- Example Job of Jobs -->
<job id="jobOfJobs">
  <step id="step1">
    <job ref="job1" />
  </step>
  <step id="step2">
    <job ref="job2" />
  </step>
</job>
```

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation on making a Step reference a Job? I'm curious, I'd imagine that would cause status and execution context implications galore. As for your problem, from the introduction, "Spring Batch is not a scheduling framework." IMO you're asking for hassles if you try to make it act as one, especially when Quartz is already in the picture.

Comment: @EmersonFarrugia thanks for the tip. I read that quote myself too before I started this effort. However, using the above I've been able to use SB effectively as a scheduling framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to manage dependencies between jobs treat them as a step using [JobStep](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html)